# golang googollee/go-socket.io module pingtimeout automatically closing socket connections

Tags: go, websocket, serversocket, io-socket

I am performing socketio operations using googollee/go-socket.io on the golang side. Even though I set the pingtimeout and pinginterval settings when opening a connection, as long as the disconnect is not triggered, it shows as connected even if the internet connection of the device connected to the socket is disconnected. Therefore, devices that are not disconnected continue to appear connected to the socket. I have left the setting I made when opening the socket below. How can I close the socket connection automatically?

```
    options := &engineio.Options{
        PingTimeout:  60 * time.Second,
        PingInterval: 30 * time.Second,
    }
    server := socketio.NewServer(options)
    go func() {
        if err := server.Serve(); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("socketio listen error: %s\n", err)
        }
    }()
    defer server.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe try to put the defer inside the func?

```
go func() {
        if err := server.Serve(); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("socketio listen error: %s\n", err)
        }
 defer server.Close()
}()
```

Comment: sorry, didn't work

Comment: was busy sorry, maybe consider adding the connect and disconnect logic like server.onConnect() and server.OnDisconnect(..) 
check the documentation https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/googollee/go-socket.io in the section for func (*Server) OnDisconnect and   func (*Server) OnConnect

Comment: I am already listening to these, but unfortunately the disconnect is not triggered in case of disconnection from the socket.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't do much to help you

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I have solved these problems for now by using the onError function.